# Jenkins Build Flow Plugin having trouble passing parameters between builds

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins, build-automation

I've got a set of parametrized builds in Jenkins that to build I have to click 'Build Now' and then enter a value for the parameter (in this case called GIT_TAG_NAME).  I'd like to trigger a set of these parametrized builds that all use the same parameter without typing it multiple times.

I'm trying to get this working with the Build Flow Plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin), by making a master build flow that triggers all the other builds, but I'm not understanding the plugin syntax, or maybe this just isn't possible.

My DSL looks like:

```
out.println "-------------------------" 
out.println 'Building all OTA builds at tag: '
out.println params["GIT_TAG_NAME"]
out.println "-------------------------"

build( "SomeOTA-Build-1", param1: params["GIT_TAG_NAME"] )
build( "SomeOTA-Build-2", param1: params["GIT_TAG_NAME"] )
```

The print statement prints the parameter correctly, but the child builds don't seem to get the parameter passed in to them.

Comment: This should work with the build flow plugin - in my setup, I can pass parameters like you describe. It works with and without specifying a parameter on `SomeOTA-Build-1`. The parameter is available as a build environment variable in `SomeOTA-Build-1` named `param1`.

Comment: The above comment contains the correct answer. The build flow plugin requires you to name the parameter you are passing in. In your case this would amount to `build( "someOTA-Build-1", GIT_TAG_NAME: params["GIT_TAG_NAME"] )`The all too short examples on the plug-in wiki page have a build with a parameter named param1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [**Parameterized Trigger Plugin**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) -

1. Set *Job-A* with a parameter `GIT_TAG_NAME` - this is your "front-end"
2. Set *Job-B1*, *Job-B2* and *Job-B3* with the same parameter `GIT_TAG_NAME` - those do the actual work
3. Set *Job-A* to **Trigger parameterized build on other projects** (in **Post-build Actions**)
    and pass **Current build parameters** to the triggered jobs
   (need a trigger per derived job - either with same or different conditions)

Now, running *Job-A* will rigger the other jobs, while passing them the value of `GIT_TAG_NAME`.

EDIT:
There is a Plugin from [TIKAL](http://www.tikalk.com/) that uses a different approach:
**[Multijob Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin)** tries to squeeze all job-steps into one big job
(have not tried it, so cannot comment on this approach).

If taking the first approach, you would probably want to take a look at the **[Join Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Join+Plugin)** -
this plugin allows a job to be run after all the immediate downstream jobs have ended.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That was just what I needed. Didn't see it among the hundreds of Jenkins plugins. :)

Comment: Well, most users want to build the same 'job' but with different configurations, so they use the [Multi-Configuration (or 'Matrix') job](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+matrix+project) .